# Update salesforce pushtopic soql query

Tags: salesforce, soql

After creating pushtopic in salesforce, how can I update the query?

ex: I need to add one more field to my query

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would suggest that you have to update the query e.g. within the developer console. First query your pushtopic and than set the query field to the new value and update the whole object
Select id, query from PushTopic where Name = '<yourPushTopicName>'

Comment: @utm - Thanks for the suggestion. It worked

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone wants the solution
Go to Developer console -> Debug -> Open Execute Anonymous Window
Then type the below

PushTopic pt = new PushTopic(Id='', Query = 'select  id, name from account');
update(pt);

execute the query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 'workbench', you can update it by manually editing the query when you select it from a list (if there are some PushTopics already created or you can create one from right there).

You get two fields, namely, Name and Query after you select your PushTopic from the dropdown. You can edit the query right there :) .

Hope this helps when and if you are using workbench to run the PushTopics and you have logged in using the same credentials as of your 'org' (Developer Console, where you have created the PushTopic).

Answer (score 0):

PushTopics are also stored in the pushtopic table and you can use soql to update them.